# Inserting data in a sorted Circular Linked List

Tags: java, linked-list, circular-list

I want to add a given data into an already sorted Circular Linked List such that the resultant list is also sorted. The class for the `Node` is already provided which have `public int data` and `public Node next` as the class members.

A function `addNode(Node head)` is to be implemented which will insert a known data(9) into the list. `Node head` is the head pointer of the circular linked list.

I have considered the following cases

1. When the list is empty, create the Node, put its data as 9 and refer its next to itself. Make the newly created node as the head.
2. When the list contains only one item. Modify the first node's next pointer to point to the new node and new node's next pointer to the given head node. Make the head node point to the node whose value is the lowest.
3. When the inserted data is the smallest among all i.e it will be smaller than the data of the node which the head node points to and it will be inserted before the Head node.
4. When the data is to be inserted between two nodes. So I am using the while loop which will find the node before which the new data will be inserted and modifying the node's next pointer accordingly.

When I am submitting the code, it is somehow failing one test case which I am not able to find out. Can someone help me in finding out the condition that I might be overlooking in my logic.

Below is the implemented code:

```
public static Node addElement(Node input1)
{
    //Write code here
Node result = new Node();
Node current = new Node();
current = input1;

Node value = new Node();
value.data = 10;

if(current == null){
    value.next = value;
    result = value;
}
else if(current.next == current){
    value.next = input1;
    current.next = value;
    result = current.data < value.data ? current : value;
}
else if(value.data < current.data){
    while(current.next != input1)
        current = current.next;     

    current.next = value;
    current.next.next = input1;
    result = current.next;
}   
else{
    while(current.next != input1 && current.next.data <= value.data)
        current = current.next;

    Node currentNext = current.next;
    current.next = value;
    current.next.next = currentNext;
    result = input1;
}

return result;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean it is failing a test case which you cannot find out? Is there a specific set of data for which it is failing?

Comment: @Christina I suppose it's homework that is checked by a number of JUnit tests. Looks like the OP doesn't know himself which test is failed.

Comment: I think there is an error in your logic for case 2. What if your new node is the lowest value? You said that the new node points to the head and the head to the node with the lowest value. You would then lose the reference to your old node. Edit: **scratch** the rest, I just saw that `input1`is supposed to be the `head node`.

Comment: In this case is it possible that it's failing because in your code you're setting value.data to 10 instead of 9 like your question asks? Assuming that it's really a constant value that you're adding to the list and you haven't just set it to be constant to make the question simpler.

Comment: Your code pretty much seems to do what you want it to do. However in your text you say you want to add a node with data `9` but in your source it's actually `10`. Maybe that's the problem? Btw, forget my comment above, I just realized that in case 2 you meant that only the head node is in the list.

Comment: @Christina I dont have the test cases. So I don't know which one is failing. Also the value is a constant..take it whatever 9 or 10 it doesn't matter.

Comment: @Sebastian_H I am taking the reference of the head node into a node called `current` and then modifying it.

Comment: Have you checked if the test case is faulty? I know you don't have them, but maybe you can ask someone. Have you asked other people if they've run into the same problem or if their code runs successfully? Everyone can make mistakes, even the one writing the test. You can look forever for an error in your code if the problem is actually on the other side.

Comment: @Sebastian_H I don't think there is any faulty test case because I see people scoring 100 (pass all 10 test case) where as mine in 90 (passing only 9 test case).

Comment: This is strange, I did my own implementation and did a few manual test. I then took your code and made the same tests. The results are identical. All the basic operations should work correctly. Is there maybe something you have not considered. For example, should the list accept duplicates? If yes, in which order should they be. Should the duplicate be inserted before or after the existing elements. Are you absolutely sure that it doesn't matter if your data is `9` or `10`? If the order is examined or the list checked for a specific number, the test might fail. Otherwise I can't see a problem.

Comment: As a side note you don't really need all thoses cases you are taking into account. The only cases you really need are 1. list empty, 2. list not empty (this will actually merge cases 2-4 above together). Perhaps by minimising the cases you are trying to handle and simplifying your code you will find something we're not seeing right now (for what it's worth I can't see any errors in your code above either).

Answer (score 0):

```
void sortedInsert(struct node** head_ref, struct node* new_node)
{
  struct node* current = *head_ref;

  // Case 1 of the above algo
  if (current == NULL)
  {
     new_node->next = new_node;
     *head_ref = new_node;
  }

  // Case 2 of the above algo
  else if (current->data >= new_node->data)
  {
    /* If value is smaller than head's value then
      we need to change next of last node */
    while(current->next != *head_ref)
        current = current->next;
    current->next = new_node;
    new_node->next = *head_ref;
    *head_ref = new_node;
  }

  // Case 3 of the above algo
  else
  {
    /* Locate the node before the point of insertion */
    while (current->next!= *head_ref && current->next->data < new_node->data)
      current = current->next;

    new_node->next = current->next;
    current->next = new_node;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please consider including some information about your answer, rather than simply posting code. We try to provide not just 'fixes', but help people learn. You should explain what was wrong in the original code, what you did differently, and why your change(s) worked.