# How to sort an existing doubly circular linked list?

Tags: c, linked-list

How can I change the location of a node in a previously created two-way circular linked list without changing the data in it?

**(First of all, I'm sorry for my bad English, English is not my native language.)**

We took the exam for the "Data Structures" course at our university. The last question was given like this.

> Check out the code given below. Complete the missing function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Node
{
    int data;
    struct Node* next;
    struct Node* pre;
};

struct Node* node_create(int data)
{
    struct Node* new_node = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    new_node->data = data;
    new_node->next = NULL;
    new_node->pre = NULL;

    return new_node;
}

void node_add(struct Node** head, struct Node* new_node)
{
    struct Node* list = *head;

    if(*head == NULL)
    {
        new_node->next = new_node;
        new_node->pre = new_node;
        *head = new_node;
    }
    else
    {
        while(list->next != *head)
        {
            list = list->next;
        }

        list->next = new_node;
        (*head)->pre = new_node;

        new_node->next = *head;
        new_node->pre = list;
    }
}

void node_list(struct Node** head)
{
    struct Node* list = *head;

    if(*head == NULL)
    {
        printf("\nEmpty Linked List!\n");
        return;
    }

    do{

        //printf("(%p) %p - %d-> (%p)", list->pre,list,list->data,list->next);
        printf("%d-> ", list->data);
        list = list->next;
    }while(list != *head);
}

void node_delete(struct Node** head, int data)
{
    if(*head == NULL)
    {
        printf("\nEmpty Linked List!\n");
        return;
    }

    struct Node* list = *head;
    struct Node* end = *head;

    if( list->data == data )
    {
        if(list->next == list)
        {
            free(list);
            *head = NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            while(end->next != *head)
            {
                end = end->next;
            }

            *head = list->next;
            end->next = *head;
            (*head)->pre = end;
            free(list);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        while(list->data != data && list->next != *head)
        {
            list = list->next;
        }

        if(list->data != data && list->next == *head)
        {
            printf("No value for delete!\n");
            return;
        }

        (list->pre)->next = list->next;
        (list->next)->pre = list->pre;
        free(list);
    }

    printf("\nDelete of complited!\n");


}

void node_sorting(struct Node** head)
{
    
}




int main()
{
    struct Node* head = NULL;
    struct Node* new_node = NULL;
    int select = 0, data = 0, one = 1;

    while(one == 1)
    {
        printf("\n\nNode Add (1)\n");
        printf("Node List (2)\n");
        printf("Node Delete (3)\n");
        printf("Node Sorting (4)\n");

        printf("\nSelect: ");
        scanf("%d", &select);

        if(select == 1)
        {
            printf("\nData: ");
            scanf("%d", &data);

            new_node = node_create(data);
            node_add(&head, new_node);
        }
        else if(select == 2)
        {
            node_list(&head);
        }
        else if(select == 3)
        {
            printf("\nData to delete: ");
            scanf("%d", &data);

            node_delete(&head, data);
        }
        else if(select == 4)
        {
            node_sorting(&head);
        }

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Thinking that the problem was easy and could be solved with the bubble algorithm, I wrote the following code as an answer.

```
void node_sorting(struct Node** head)
{
    struct Node* list = *head;
    struct Node* tolist = *head;

    if(*head == NULL)
    {
        printf("\nEmpty Linked List!\n");
        return;
    }

    if((*head)->next == *head)
    {
        printf("A single-element linked list cannot be sorted.");
        return;
    }

    do{

        tolist = list->next;
        list = list->next;

        while(tolist != *head)
        {
            if(list->data > tolist->data)
            {
                int temp = 0;
                temp = tolist->data;
                tolist->data = list->data;
                list->data = temp;
            }
    
            tolist = tolist->next;
        }


    }while(list != *head);

}
```

However, when the results were announced, I learned that I failed the exam and got a 0 in the question above.

When I talked to the professor teaching the course, I got the following answer. "The answer you wrote is just a scam. If I used this in real life, could cause serious damage. Never change the data. Change the position of the nodes."

I didn't understand what this was. I researched this for 1 week and found the following resources.

[Inserting data in a sorted Circular Linked List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12490428/inserting-data-in-a-sorted-circular-linked-list)

[Inserting a element in a singly circular linked list in sorted manner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57966920/inserting-a-element-in-a-singly-circular-linked-list-in-sorted-manner)

[Insert element into a sorted Circular Double Linked List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31362968/insert-element-into-a-sorted-circular-double-linked-list)

None of these are suitable for sorting an existing doubly circular linked list. Any file or text that you can share with me that suits my request will be very helpful to me. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: merge-sort works quite well for linked lists. Elements are reordered by changing next/prev pointers without moving actual data between nodes.

Comment: @tstanisl First of all, thank you for your answer. I'm a novice in these matters, can I give a little more detail? We were not allowed to create a new circular linked list in the exam. What needed to be done had to be done in the existing linked list.

Comment: If you know how to unlink a node from the list, and how to splice it into another position in the list, then it should be straightforward to implement a merge sort or perhaps shell sort.  If not, then that's something you really ought to learn and understand.

Comment: @TobySpeight Thanks for your answer. I tried this but got many exceptions. Are there any resources that do this? I would be very happy if you share it. I searched on the internet but couldn't find any results.

Comment: IMO, the simplest, albeit not the most efficient, solution is to do selection sort and only swap the `data` component as needed instead of reordering list elements.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Thanks for your answer. But we don't need to make any changes to the 'data'. Our lecturer said that we should only use it as a comparison criterion.

Comment: Your teacher does not seem to have good teaching skills. Calling your solution a "scam" is a big exaggeration, and not motivating for their students. If the purpose is to sort the list by not writing to the `data` member (which *is* reasonable), this should be mentioned in the exercise description.

Comment: @trincot Thanks very much for your answer. I definitely agree with you. I've been dealing with this problem for a week. The teacher's attitude really upset me. But this is how the software world must be. I continue to research. I haven't found the answer to this question yet.

Comment: Split odd and even nodes into to two separate lists. Sort each list recursively. Next combine both sorted list into a new one by popping the smaller top element from one of two list. There are some edge cases but this will let you sort a list in deterministic O(N * log N).

Comment: The data payload in the example list is just an integer.  In more realistic scenarios, the data could be bigger — possibly much bigger.   OTOH, it would often be just a pointer to a structure which isn't much different from an integer.

Comment: `void node_add()` traverses the entire _ring_ of nodes (instead of using the `pre` pointer.) Tell your prof that the best solution would be to build the ring of nodes in sorted order from the outset... "In the real world", not checking that `malloc()` succeeded deserves a failing grade... Yes, welcome to the fraternity where you'll be encountering some distasteful egos...

Comment: I updated my answer. It includes a simple insertion sort, an iterative bottom up merge sort and a recursive bottom up merge sort that reorders (change the locations of) nodes within a circular double linked list to sort the list, using a 6 line list_splice() function to move a node within a list, without the usage of any created lists. Sorted runs within the list are created by reordering nodes using list_splice(), and the code keeps track of the run boundaries. No other lists or nodes are created to perform the sort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is that you update the `pre` and `next` members so that the nodes get placed in a different order.

Here is an implementation of merge sort that uses that principle. It consists of these steps:

1. Check whether the given list has zero or one node only: in that case the list is sorted and we can return. If not:
2. Find the middle node in the given list.
3. Split the list into two circular lists, so that this node becomes the head of the second list. This means some `pre`, `next` pointers have to be updated.
4. Perform this algorithm for each of the two smaller lists
5. Now these two lists are sorted: merge them into one sorted, circular list.

Here are the functions to add to your code to make it work like that:

```
struct Node* extract_head(struct Node** head) {
    struct Node *node = *head;
    // Detach node from the list it is in
    node->pre->next = node->next;
    node->next->pre = node->pre;
    // Make next node the new head
    *head = node == node->next ? NULL : node->next;
    // Return the node we have extracted
    return node;
}

struct Node* get_middle_node(struct Node* head) {
    if (!head) return head;
    struct Node *last = head->pre;
    // Walk forward and backwards until the two pointers meet:
    while (head != last) {
        head = head->next; // Forward
        if (head == last) break;
        last = last->pre;  // Backward
    }
    return head;
}

struct Node* merge(struct Node* left, struct Node* right) {
    struct Node *newHead = NULL;
    while (left || right) { // While there are nodes to merge...
        // Move the node with the least value into a new circular list
        node_add(&newHead, extract_head(
            !right || left && left->data < right->data ? &left : &right
        ));
    }
    return newHead;
}

struct Node* split_at(struct Node *head, struct Node *at) {
    struct Node *tail = at->pre;
    at->pre = head->pre;
    head->pre->next = at;
    head->pre = tail;
    tail->next = head;
    // Return the pointer to the second half that was separated
    return at;
}

struct Node* merge_sort(struct Node* head) {
    return !head || head->next == head ? head // One node only? => is sorted
         // Split in two, sort each, and merge:
         : merge(merge_sort(split_at(head, get_middle_node(head))), 
                 merge_sort(head));
}

void node_sorting(struct Node** head)
{
    *head = merge_sort(*head);
}
```

Not your question, but the code you provided has some strange particularities. For instance, you have in `node_add` and `node_delete` some `while` loops that traverse the whole list only to stop at the last node in the list. But this last node is the predecessor of the head node, so you could just have looked at `(*head)->pre` to find it!

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for your answer and detailed explanation. Believe me, you have been a great help. I'm sorry for my late answer. I learned the code you wrote by trying to write it myself, step by step. And here it WORKS. I will share my entire code with explanations soon, there might be someone who needs it.

Comment: @BaranKanat - not in the question but in your first comment: "We were not allowed to create a new circular linked list in the exam", but that is literally what `merge()` does, creating a new circular linked list starting with `newHead = NULL`, and then using `node_add()` to add nodes extracted from the original list to the new list. This could be resolved by changing `merge()` to splice (change the location of) nodes within the existing list, similar to C++ std::list::splice().

Comment: @rcgldr, I understand the requirement to be: don't create a new list *aside* from the existing list, i.e. with new memory allocated for new nodes. This answer just mutates the `pre` `next` pointers of the existing set of nodes, which is what I understood was the requirement. But the asker can confirm if they still read this.

Answer (score 2):

> How can I change the location of a node in a previously created two-way circular linked list without changing the data in it?

"Location" in this sense is about the order in which nodes will be traversed as you follow the chain of `next` pointers (or `pre` pointers if you traverse the list in the other direction).  It follows that to change a node's location, you modify various nodes' `next` and `pre` pointers.

For example, consider this initial order (showing only the `next` pointers) ...

```
    A  --->  B  --->  C  --->  D
```

... and suppose we want to swap nodes B and C.  That means we want to modify the list so that forward iteration proceeds from A to C to B to D.  Well that already tells you where the pointers should be modified to point:

```
    r----------------\
    |                 V 
    A        B  <---  C        D
             |                 ^
             L----------------/
```

Of course, for a doubly-linked list, you need to update the `pre` pointers consistently with the `next` pointers.

You do need to take into account not just the pointers between the two nodes being swapped, but also the ones between those and the ones to either side -- A and D in the example.

Overall, you can conceptualize moving a node from one position to another as removing that node from the list without deallocating it, then re-inserting it at the wanted position.  You can implement it that way, too, albeit not, in your case, by calling your given `node_add` and `node_delete` functions.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I change the location of a node in a previously created two-way circular linked list without changing the data in it?

With a double linked list, you can change the location of a node by removing the node and inserting it elsewhere with 6 lines of code.  In the following code, list_splice(left, right) removes the right node and inserts it before the left node:

```
a <- left <- b <- ... <- c <- right <- d    before move
a -> left -> b -> ... -> c -> right -> d
a <- right <- left <- b <- ... <- c <- d    after move
a -> right -> left -> b -> ... -> c -> d
```

Note the code in this answer is based on old code that uses Hungarian (Microsoft Windows) naming conventions for variables, where there is a prefix for the type such as `p` for pointer or `ap` for array of pointers.

Insertion sort using the list_splice() function to change the locations of nodes within the list to sort the list. Nodes are removed from the list and inserted back into the front of the list in sorted order.

```
/* list_splice assumes pLft != pRgt */
void list_splice(struct Node* pLft, struct Node* pRgt)
{
struct Node* pNod = pRgt;
    pRgt->prev->next = pRgt->next;      /* remove right node */
    pRgt->next->prev = pRgt->prev;
    pRgt->prev = pLft->prev;            /* insert right node */
    pRgt->next = pLft;                  /*  before left node */
    pLft->prev->next = pRgt;
    pLft->prev = pRgt;
}

void list_sort(struct Node** list)
{
struct Node* pFst;                      /* first node of list */
struct Node* pOld;                      /* beg old list */
struct Node* pNxt;                      /* nxt old list */
struct Node* pNew;                      /* cur new list */
    if(list == NULL || *list == NULL)   /* check for null ptr */
        return;
    pFst = *list;
    if(pFst == pFst->next)              /* check for single node */
        return;
    pNxt = pFst->next;                  /* insert old into new */
    for(pOld = pNxt; pOld != pFst; pOld = pNxt){
        pNxt = pOld->next;
        pNew = pFst;
        while(pNew != pOld && pNew->data <= pOld->data)
            pNew = pNew->next;
        if(pNew != pOld){
            list_splice(pNew, pOld);
            if(pNew == pFst)
                pFst = pOld;
        }
    }
    *list = pFst;                       /* update ptr to list */
}
```

---

Bottom up merge sort for circular double linked list. Unlike top down merge sort, bottom up eliminates the need to traverse lists in order to split them, improving performance. All merging is performed by reordering (changing the location of) nodes within the original list via list_splice(). When merging, only out of order nodes are moved. The original list of `n` nodes is considered as `n` runs (sorted sub-lists) of 1 node each. Two runs of 1 node each are merged to create a run of 2 nodes; two runs of 2 nodes are merged to create a run of 4 nodes; two runs of 4 nodes are merged to create a run of 8 nodes; ... The run boundaries within the original list are kept track of via local variables and in a small (32) array of pointers, where array[i] is NULL or a pointer to a run with 2^i nodes. The original list is reordered to create a set of runs tracked by the array, then those runs tracked by the array are merged resulting in a reordered and sorted original list. All merges involve adjacent runs: list_merge() takes three pointers as parameters, start of left run, start of right run == end of left run, end of right run.

```
struct Node* list_merge(struct Node* pLft, struct Node* pRgt, struct Node* pEnd)
{
struct Node* pNod;
struct Node *pNxt;
    /* set ptr to fisrt node of merged list (return value) */
    pNod = (pRgt->data < pLft->data) ? pRgt : pLft;
    while(1){                           /* merge lists */
        if(pRgt->data < pLft->data){
            pNxt = pRgt->next;
            list_splice(pLft, pRgt);
            pRgt = pNxt;
            if(pRgt == pEnd)
                return pNod;
        } else {
            pLft = pLft->next;
            if(pLft == pRgt)
                return pNod;
        }
    }
}

#define ASZ 32
void list_sort(struct Node** list)
{
struct Node* apNd[ASZ] = {NULL};        /* array of ptrs to runs */
struct Node* pFst;                      /* first node of list */
struct Node* pRgt;                      /* right pointer */
struct Node* pEnd;                      /* end|wrk pointer */
size_t i;

    if(list == NULL || *list == NULL)   /* check for null ptr */
        return;
    pFst = *list;
    if(pFst == pFst->next)              /* check for single node */
        return;
    pEnd = pFst;                        /* merge nodes into array */
    do{
        pRgt = pEnd;
        pEnd = pEnd->next;
        for(i = 0; i < ASZ && apNd[i] != NULL; i++){
            pRgt = list_merge(apNd[i], pRgt, pEnd);
            if(apNd[i] == pFst)
                pFst = pRgt;
            apNd[i] = NULL;
        }
        if(i == ASZ)                    /*   don't go past end array */
            i--;
        apNd[i] = pRgt;
    }while(pEnd != pFst);

    /* merge array into single sorted list */
    for(i = 0; i < ASZ && apNd[i] == NULL; i++);
    pRgt = apNd[i++];
    while(1){
        for( ; i < ASZ && apNd[i] == NULL; i++);
        if (i == ASZ)
            break;
        pRgt = list_merge(apNd[i++], pRgt, pEnd);
    }
    *list = pRgt;                       /* update ptr to list */
}
```

Bottom up merge sort can also be implemented with a recursive function that tracks run boundaries on the stack instead of a small array, but it needs a  count.

```
/* assumes initial cnt >= 2, 0 or 1 handled by caller */
struct Node* list_sortr(struct Node** ppLft, size_t cnt)
{
struct Node* pLft = *ppLft;
struct Node* pRgt;
struct Node* pEnd;
    if(cnt == 1)
        return pLft->next;
    pRgt = list_sortr(&pLft, cnt-cnt/2);
    pEnd = list_sortr(&pRgt,     cnt/2);
    pLft = list_merge(pLft, pRgt, pEnd);
    *ppLft = pLft;
    return pEnd;
}

void list_sort(struct Node** list)      /* entry function */
{
struct Node* pFst;
struct Node* pNod;
size_t cnt = 1;
    if(list == NULL || *list == NULL)   /* check for null ptr */
        return;
    pFst = *list;
    if(pFst == pFst->next)              /* check for single node */
        return;
    /* generate cnt for list_sortr() */
    for(pNod = pFst->next; pNod != pFst; pNod = pNod->next)
        cnt++;
    list_sortr(list, cnt);              /* recursive merge sort */
}
```